# See a JWS apps stack trace?

Tags: java, java-web-start

How can I view a JWS apps stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Java Web Start you are referring to then you need to go into your Java settings and turn the console on.  (Set it to "Always" show.)  Next time you click the JNLP then the console will launch and you can see whatever your app is dumping.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the stack trace will also print to the console if you run the JNLP from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that in Java 6 you can programatically generate a complete thread dump which can then be printed to System.out.